# How to cancel auto filter on table with openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

The title said it all :)

But still, I'm using the class `Table` from `openpyxl.worksheet.table` to define a table in excel file which I create. My problem is that the table that is created has `Filter` on the first row that I want to remove (from the script, not by opening the Excel file).

This  is the calling for Table class:

```
tab = Table(displayName='Table_{}'.format(table_name.replace(' ', '_')),
                                          ref="{}:{}".format(table_start, table_end))
```

This is what I get:

[image]

This is what I want to get:

[image]

I search for it at OpenPyXL Docs but find only adding that filtering...

There is any way to remove this?

Many thanks!

Comment: This is more a question about the OOXML specification than openpyxl and I don't see anything in it that makes specific reference to this. You're best off comparing the XML for the relevant tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
wb = load_workbook(filename="data.xlsx")
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
ws.auto_filter.ref = None
for i in range(2, ws.max_row + 1):
    ws.row_dimensions[i].hidden = False
wb.save("data.xlsx")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across this and here is how I solved it.

```
#Opens the file
wb = load_workbook(filename = 'somefile')

#Set worksheet
ws = wb['sheetname'] # Tab name

#set table
tbl = ws.tables["tablename"]

#removes all filters 
tbl.autoFilter.filterColumn.clear()
```

Comment: for me after creating a table and `sheet.add_table(tab1)`, I got `tab1.autoFilter` is `None`

Answer (score -1):

helo,

```
tab = Table( displayName='Table_{}'.format(table_name.replace(' ', '_'))
       , ref="{}:{}".format(table_start, table_end)
       , headerRowCount = 0 # default is 1
       )
```

Comment: Please consider adding a little bit of explanation what exactly your answer is doing, and where your improvements over OPs method are.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, it just turns the header row into a regular row.